# How to create element range index in Marklogic?

Tags: xml, xquery, indexing, marklogic

I have the following xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<patent-assignment>
  <assignment-record>
    <correspondent>
      <name>NORTH AMERICA INTERNATIONAL PATENT OFFIC</name>
      <address-1>P.O. BOX 506</address-1>
      <address-2>MERRIFIELD, VA 22116</address-2>
    </correspondent>
   </assignment-record>
  <patent-assignors>
    <patent-assignor>
      <name>TSAI, YU-WEN</name>
      <execution-date>
    <date>20050331</date>
      </execution-date>
    </patent-assignor>
    <patent-assignor>
      <name>HUANG, CHENG-I</name>
      <execution-date>
    <date>20050331</date>
      </execution-date>
    </patent-assignor>
  </patent-assignors>
  <patent-assignees>
    <patent-assignee>
      <name>FARADAY TECHNOLOGY CORP.</name>
      <address-1>NO.10-2, LI-HSIN ROAD 1, SCIENCE-BASED INDUSTRIAL PARK</address-1>
      <city>HSIN-CHU CITY</city>
      <country-name>TAIWAN</country-name>
    </patent-assignee>
  </patent-assignees>
 </patent-assignment>
```

Now I want to create range element indexes on names of **patent-Assignor** and **patent-Assignee**.  But in Marklogic there is no option to specify XPath for range indexes. It will just take the index name as "name".  So what will be the proper way to create element range indexes on names of **patent-Assignor** and **patent-Assignee** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puneet, in order to get just one set of names, MarkLogic needs to be able to distinguish between the sets somehow. Your best bet is to change the name element's localname (currently "name") or namespace (currently none) during ingest. After doing so, you can build an element-range-index and use cts:element-values(). For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<patent-assignment>
  <assignment-record>
    <correspondent>
      <name>NORTH AMERICA INTERNATIONAL PATENT OFFIC</name>
      <address-1>P.O. BOX 506</address-1>
      <address-2>MERRIFIELD, VA 22116</address-2>
    </correspondent>
  </assignment-record>
  <patent-assignors xmlns="http://puneet/assignors">
    <patent-assignor>
      <name>TSAI, YU-WEN</name>
      <execution-date>
        <date>20050331</date>
      </execution-date>
    </patent-assignor>
    <patent-assignor>
      <name>HUANG, CHENG-I</name>
      <execution-date>
        <date>20050331</date>
      </execution-date>
    </patent-assignor>
  </patent-assignors>
  <patent-assignees xmlns="http://puneet/assignees">
    <patent-assignee>
      <name>FARADAY TECHNOLOGY CORP.</name>
      <address-1>NO.10-2, LI-HSIN ROAD 1, SCIENCE-BASED INDUSTRIAL PARK</address-1>
      <city>HSIN-CHU CITY</city>
      <country-name>TAIWAN</country-name>
    </patent-assignee>
  </patent-assignees>
</patent-assignment>
```

From this XML, you can build a range index on each of the "name" elements, then call

```
cts:element-values(fn:QName("http://puneet/assignees", "name"))
```

to get the assignee names.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cts:path-range-query()` for patent-assignors and patent-assignee

1. `cts:path-range-query("/patent-assignors/patent-assignor","=",$name)`
2. `cts:path-range-query("/patent-assignees/patent-assignor","=",$name)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about the parent or ancestors of the element. You can restrict a element-range-query or element-value-query on an ancestor by wrapping it in an element-query:

```
cts:element-query(xs:QName("patent-assignor"), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("name"), "my value"))
```

You can search on names with different ancestors in a single call by passing in a sequence as first param to cts:element-query:

```
cts:element-query((xs:QName("patent-assignor"), xs:QName("patent-assignee")), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("name"), "my value"))
```

HTH!

Comment: But I don't want to search. I want to return all the distinct patent-assignor name and patent-assignee name and for that I want index on name. In cts:element-value-query I have to pass a second argument as the value to search for. But I dont want to search anything. I just want to return all the distinct names.

Comment: @puneet-pant Sorry, that wasn't clear from your question. But not a problem at all, you don't need to search to make this work. You can pass in the very same query to `cts:element-values` (as 3rd argument) as you would use for search.

Comment: I am unable to understand what are u saying. Could you please write the full query.

Comment: @Eric Bloch when I use cts:element-values(xs:QName("patent-assignee")) it gives all the element values including name, address, city etc. But I want only name. How do I get only patent-assignee names ?

Comment: cts:element-values(xs:QName("name"))