# Return unique element values from large database

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic, nosql

I have a large ML database setup (around 40,000) different XML files and need to get a list of unique keyword elements from all of the files, where there are multiple per file.

I have used a couple of queries and each one returns a different issue

```
for $doc in (cts:search(fn:collection(), cts:element-query(xs:QName("kwd"),())))
return fn:distinct-values($doc/article/.../kwd/string())
```

expanded tree cache full

```
for $doc in fn:distinct-values(cts:search(/article/.../kwd, cts:element-query(xs:QName(()),())))
return $doc
```

this returns a list of unique results but takes an eternity to load and prepends the output  with "xs:UntypedAtomic(...". Using string() in return query says "this is not a node"

How can i get this working?

Comment: Is kwd in a namespace other than what you specified in the range-index setting? Could you post an xml snippet?

Comment: BTW `cts:element-query(xs:QName("kwd"),())` will return empty sequence. You probably want `cts:element-query(xs:QName("kwd"), cts:and-query(()))` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Without indexes:

```
fn:distinct-values(collection()/article//kwd)
```

This solution doesn't scale well though, and is likely slow. I recommend adding a range index on either the element kwd or the path article//kwd. Then use something like this to get the unique values (from element range index):

```
cts:element-values(xs:QName('kwd'))
```

For a path range index you need to use [cts:values()](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values). These value lexicons give response in sub second, up to below millisecond.

HTH!

Comment: I tried adding a range index to kwd but it couldn't find the element, which seemed a bit odd. I added the range index to one of the parent elements to see if that worked. I then tried running the cts:element-values query and got the error "No element range index for fn:QName...". How can i get all elements to be available for indexing?

Comment: You said "it couldn't find the element." Did you get an error, or did you just not get any results when you called element-values()?If you're adding the parent element you'll need a path range index, not an element range index, and as grtjn said, you'll need to call cts:values() and not cts:element-values().

Comment: The error `XDMP-ELEMATTRRIDXNOTFOUND` `No element range index` doesn't mean the element can't be found. Instead it means the specification passed to `cts:element-values` doesn't match any existing index. That's probably a config bug or a code bug or both, on your side. The answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578706/how-to-create-element-range-index-in-marklogic may help, or review https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index and https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/grokking-the-cts-api — or post a new question with the details.